# Take fixture item by reference in nelmio-alice

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I have a set of fixtures (here is a simplification):

```
My\Entity\User:
  user_{1..10}:
    name: <firstName()>

My\Entity\Item:
  item_{1..10}:
    user: '@user_$current'
    data: <numberBetween(111111111, 999999999)>
```

I want to fetch `Item` with ID `4` inside my phpunit functional test.

I can't be sure that autoincrement ID is started from 1. It's not 1 after `TRUNCATE`. So this is **incorrect**:

```
$item4 = $this->em->getRepository(Item::class)->find(4);
```

How can I get a reference to `item_4`?

Comment: I don´t know an elegant solution, so what´s about remapping the keys?

Comment: Can you add the part of your code that loads the fixtures? The Loader that loads the fixture file will return an array with all the entities. From this array you can get the entity instead of fetching it via the entity manager. If you want to make sure, you can find it, you can use this entity's id to pass to `find()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the entities generated from the fixtures file directly from the loader:

```
$loader = new Nelmio\Alice\Loader\NativeLoader();
$objectSet = $loader->loadFile(__DIR__.'/fixtures.yml');
```

The `$objectSet` should contain all your entities by their alias, so you can get a specific item and directly work with it or fetch it again using your repository

```
$fixtureItem4 = $objectSet['item_4'];
$persistedItem4 = $this->em->getRepository(Item::class)->find($fixtureItem4->getId());
```